# Backup from ubuntu to windows

Tags: windows-7, backup, ubuntu-server, scheduled-tasks

I'm having trouble finding some way to backup files from my ubuntu server to my windows 7 client. This is over the internet so I can't use robocopy or similar.

Does anyone know about a program or script that copy folder from my ubuntu (over ftps, sftp or something) server to my windows 7 client?

Comment: Robocopy can copy over the internet given a hardware server, but I'll suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows [supports FTP Batch Scripts](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/96269) or you count use [WinSCP in a command line way](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline).

Comment: The trouble with backing up to a Windows machine is that the file system doesn't support some of the file naming conventions in Linux, which is something to be aware of.